# psych::alpha will not run when I include a particular variable

Tags: r, psych

I am attempting to calculate the internal consistency for a scale with 28 items.

`alpha(df)` fails with

```
Likely variables with missing values are  dast11_recode dast20  
Error in principal(x, scores = FALSE) : 
  I am sorry: missing values (NAs) in the correlation matrix do not allow me to continue.
Please drop those variables and try again.
In addition: Warning message:
In cor(r, use = use) : the standard deviation is zero
```

The variable 'dast20' appears to be causing the issue, as running `alpha(select(df, -dast20))` runs fine.

`alpha(na.omit(df))` also runs fine, but gives the warning

```
Item = dast20 had no variance and was deleted but still is counted in the score
```

`var(df$dast20) = 0.0009784736`

Specifically, `dast20` contains 1022 observations (`'0' - 1021; '1' - 1`).

I'd like to understand why this is causing me problems so I can determine the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze the frequencies of the classes inside the variable `dast20`:

`table(df$dast20)`

you will see that you have no variability, so it is not a variable, it does not add anything to the estimation of Cronbach's α.

Comment: As mentioned above there is a very small amount of variability here 'var(df$dast20)' = 0.0009784736

Does psych::alpha() round this?

Comment: Check if the observation where `df$dast20==1` has any missing value in any other variable.